# (REACT) How to re-render component(with updated values) from another component?

Tags: reactjs

How do I make a **component re-render another component** with new values from the local storage?
I'm trying to **update some of the Navbar elements** after the Login component has received the user data from the backend API and placed it in **localStorage**.

I've already tried several things like using useEffect to look for changes in the props that I'm sending from the Login component, I'm still needing to manually refresh to see changes in the Navbar.

```html
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import '../style/index.scss';
import '../style/Navbar.scss';

function Navbar({refresh}) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    //Array of the navbar links
    let navBarItems = [
        {
            title : 'Home',
            url: '/home',
            class: 'nav-links'
        },
        {
            title : 'Members',
            url: '/members',
            class: 'nav-links'
        },
        {
            title : 'Login',
            url: '/members/login',
            class: 'nav-links'
        },
        {
            title : 'About us',
            url: '/aboutUs',
            class: 'nav-links'
        },
        {
            url: '/searchMembers',
            class: 'searchIcon',
        }
    ];

    useEffect(()=> {
        //console.log(':::::'+ user + ' '+ refresh);
        setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedInUser')));
    },[refresh]);

    return (
        <div className='navbar'>
            <div className='logoName'><div className='advocateIcon'></div><a href='/'>{(user)? 'Hi '+user.member.name.firstName : 'Bar-Council Members'}</a></div>
            <div className='navchunk'>
                {navBarItems.map((item, index)=> {
                    return (
                        <a key={'navLink'+index} className={item.class+' links'} href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have a parent component which contains a state, which is passed down to both child components. When your api returns the data, you would set local storage and change the state, for example...

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

const NavBar = ({yourState}) => <p>{yourState}</p>

const Login = ({yourState, setYourState}) => <button onClick={() => setYourState("world!")}></button>

const App = () => {
  const [yourState, setYourState] = useState('Hello')
  return (
    <div>
      <Login 
        yourState={yourState}
        setYourState={setYourState}
      />
      <NavBar 
        yourState={yourState}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Was probably overthinking it, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Would you mind marking my answer as solved please?